# What is faster? Build Layout programmatically or import XML Files?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Is it faster to import ready xml files or build up the layout with code?

I have a for loop, which adds circa 140 LinearLayouts, and fills them.
Would it be faster when I Import the Layouts as xml Files?

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ChannelList.size(); i++){
    LinearLayout channel = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams channelLayoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(600, 9800);
    channel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView channelTitle = new TextView(this);
    channelTitle.setHeight(200);
    channelTitle.setWidth(600);
    channelTitle.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    channelTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
    channelTitle.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
    channelTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    channelTitle.setText(ChannelList.get(i));
    channelTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));

    channel.addView(channelTitle);

    LinearLayout channelContent = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams channelContentLayoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    channelContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    channel.addView(channelContent,channelContentLayoutParam);
    channelList.addView(channel,channelLayoutParam);
}
```

Comment: Importing is always faster, your code is a lot cleaner and from my experience your code will have less run time errors, ticks and less skipped frames. :) You can test this out on an emulator form Eclipse, it'll start telling you that importing skips less frames. And besides that, your code will look a lot cleaner! ( my experience )

Comment: Parsing XML and creating a layout, vs. creating a layout... I don't think there will be a notable difference, but I'd wonder why you are using 140 LinearLayouts rather than a ListView?

Comment: Build from XML is usually a better choice. Cleaner code, better for correct mistakes, better for separating View from Activity (or presenter or controller or whatever your pattern is) etc. I use java version for some situations, but I absolutely prefer XML. Cleaner code.

Comment: Its a horizontal layout. Don't find a example without additional Libarys to implent horizontal ListViews

Comment: Adding 140 linear layouts will kill your app's performance. You are much better off using an adapter-based approach that recycles views.

Comment: Hm, ok ... I will search for a tutorial

Comment: You could try Grid Lists: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html

Comment: Need a horizontal and vertical scrolling. I think that doesn't work with Grids